# How to sort by derived SQL columns in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-connection

I'm having issues sorting the highest rated posts on my WordPress website.

I'd like to sort and display the highest scored posts (`rating_full`) that also have the most votes (`rating_count`).

Both are of type: LongString.

Sort Example:

Business 4 has a rating 4.5/5 - 3 votes

Business 2 has a rating 4.5/5 - 1 votes

Business 1 has a rating 3.5/5 - 2 votes

In code areas of interest:

The orderby rating is the section I'm concerned about in code.

```
($orderby == 'rating')
```

The rating score for a post in code is **'rating_full'**. (Scale is 1 to 5)

The vote counts for a post in code is **'rating_count'** (Number of votes)

Both are of type: LongString

Here is an image of the database structure and data:
http://s22.postimg.org/wojlwqlz5/database.png

Here is my code below. I notice my sorting does not always sort the posts in order based on rating_full. I'm not sure why. I have not tried to implement the count DESC as I'm unsure.

```
// Sorting
add_filter('posts_join', 'directorySortingJoin',10,2);
function directorySortingJoin($join, $query) {
global $wpdb, $aThemeOptions;
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin && ((isset($_GET['dir-    search'])) || (isset($query->query_vars["ait-dir-item-category"])) ||         (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-location"])))) {
    $sql = "";
    // default ordering
    $orderby = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby)) ?  $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby : 'post_date';
    // get from get parameters
    if (!empty($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    }
    if ($orderby == 'rating') {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} rating ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID  = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key IN ('rating_full'))";
    }
    if ($orderby == 'packages') {
        directorySaveUserPackagesToDb();
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} packages ON ({$wpdb- >posts}.post_author = packages.user_id AND packages.meta_key IN    ('dir_package'))";
    }
    if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} featured ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = featured.post_id AND featured.meta_key IN ('dir_featured'))";
    }
    $join .= $sql;
    }
return $join;
    }
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'directorySortingOrderby',10,2);
    function directorySortingOrderby($orderby, $query) {
global $wpdb, $aThemeOptions;
if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin && ((isset($_GET['dir-  search'])) || (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-category"])) ||     (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-location"])))) {
    $sql = "";
    // default ordering
    $orderby = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby)) ?     $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby : 'post_date';
    $order = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrder)) ? $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrder : 'DESC';
    // get from get parameters
    if (!empty($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['order'])) {
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    }
    if ($orderby == 'rating') {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, convert(rating.meta_value, decimal) {$order}";
        } else {
            $sql = "convert(rating.meta_value, decimal) {$order}";
        }
    } else if ($orderby == 'packages') {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, packages.meta_value   {$order}";
        } else {
            $sql = "packages.meta_value {$order}";
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, {$wpdb->posts}.{$orderby}   {$order}";
        }
    }
    $orderby = $sql;
       }
  return $orderby;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! convert was used instead of cast.

$sql = "convert(rating.meta_value, decimal) {$order}";

**$sql = "cast(rating.meta_value as decimal(10,2)) {$order}";**